# Select List of Poco classes for specific entityState

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, change-tracking

I've got a piece of software that is adding entries to a context.
using the changetracker I want to generate a List of Poco classes for reporting purposes.

Like this:

```
List<customRecord> addedRecords = context.ChangeTracker.Entries<customRecord>().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added).ToList();
```

the result is the following Error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry<T>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>'
```

is there some kind of way to achieve this?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `.Select(i => i.Entity)`

```
List<customRecord> addedRecords = context.ChangeTracker.Entries<customRecord>().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added).Select(i => i.Entity).ToList();
```